# Postfix virtual mailbox - mail rejected if 'myhostname' is not 'localhost'

Tags: ubuntu, email, postfix, email-server

I'm using [this howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostfixVirtualMailBoxClamSmtpHowto) to setup virtual mailboxes for non-linux accounts using postfix.

This part of my main.cnf:

```
myhostname = localhost
mydomain = aviacao.pt
myorigin = aviacao.pt
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
mailbox_size_limit = 0
virtual_mailbox_domains = aviacao.pt
virtual_mailbox_base = /home/vmail
virtual_mailbox_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/vmaps
virtual_minimum_uid = 1000
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
relay_host = 
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
```

This works, but only when myhostname is set to localhost. If I set myhostname to aviacao.pt, it won't receive emails:

> 550 5.1.1 : Recipient address rejected: User unknown in local recipient table

Why is this the case? The howto even says that setting the myhostname as localhost can cause problems:

> Using localhost as myhostname can cause problems since this variable is used       > in the EHLO message the server sends.

Is this the best way? Will problems will this cause?

Comment: Apart from anything else, in mynetwork you should also put the IPv6 address of localhost, http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#mynetworks, since you have inet_interfaces = all (which means Ipv4 and Ipv6)

Comment: aviacao.pt is a domain name, not a hostname. (eg mx.aviacao.pt is a hostname)

Answer (score 0):

Set myhostname back to "`aviacao.pt`"

Add the line:

```
mydestination = aviacao.pt, localhost, localhost.localdomain
```